# Ubuntu Blu-ray burner suddenly not detected

Tags: ubuntu, wine, burning, blu-ray, imgburn

Have been using a Blu-ray burner from Asus on Ubuntu with Imgburn via Wine for many years. Then all of the sudden Imgburn says "No devices detected".

This has happened either because of an update, or because I installed Samba. Not sure which one is to blame.

I can easily read Blu-ray discs. I just can't get any burner app - not K3b either, to detect any Blu-ray burners all of the sudden.

I put the drive in the girlfriend's Windows machine instead, where it works fine. Then bought another drive for myself, which gives me the same problem.

Does anyone have any ideas here? Thanks.

Comment: Since you can't find it with `k3b` it's likely not a `wine` issue. Which Ubuntu release/variant are you using? what is the kernel version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. I don't think it's a wine issue either. The weird thing is that it reads any disc fine. It even allows me to burn CD and DVD. I just can't burn Blu-ray anymore weirdly. I think it looks a lot like some update came along and changed something.

Comment: `lshw -C disk` gives me `capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram` so bd-r and others are missing. I assume that line used to contain "bd-r" and others. If I try burning a Blu-ray ISO with growisofs, it complains that the ISO is too big to fit on a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a kernel problem.
Starting from linux-image-4.4.0-98 there's a problem detecting Blu-ray burners.
linux-image-4.4.0-97 works though.
Ubuntu devs has been informed, so hopefully it'll be fixed in the next kernel.

EDIT: This was fixed in kernel 4.4.0-128 but then reintroduced again in kernel 4.4.0-130 :-(

Comment: Was the bug fixed?

Comment: Sadly no. The ticket was instead closed because it "expired".
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1737671

Comment: It might be re-opened if you can do that verification thing to check whether the problem's there in the latest version; [here's a link that makes it easier](https://www.digitalpeer.com/blog/install-pre-built-upstream-kernels-in-ubuntu) though that doesn't include uninstalling. Uninstalling is described simply [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Uninstalling_upstream_kernels). They all assume that you have the GRUB prompt when you start your computer, so you can choose your version of Linux to use with Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, since I reported the problem there were several new kernel releases. I posted a comment each time reporting that the problem was still there. For now I'll just boot on kernel 97 whenever I need to burn something. But I'll test everytime there's a new kernel.

Comment: Those aren't new kernels. Those are kernels that have been in the pipeline for hundreds(?) of weeks, receiving minor bug fixes but otherwise not being changed very much at all.

Comment: I see. It's clear that I don't know much about this topic. I will see if I can figure out that upstream thingy at some point....

Comment: Once you've restarted with the upstream kernel enabled, make sure to be quick and not to do anything other than testing the drive; it's not guaranteed not to corrupt data and stuffs (though I'd bet money that it would be fine, paranoia is always useful).

Comment: There's no way I dare try this on my main machine. :-) I may try it out on a dedicated test PC.

Comment: It only has a chance of corrupting files if you open them... Probably. I wouldn't be _that_ careful, but I would also have a backup so I suppose it evens out... Ish. Just make sure that the problem occurs on your test machine first. :-)